# Double underscore '__' in BEM of NextJS Css module throw error

Tags: next.js, css-modules, bem

I'm new to Nextjs and BEM naming convention, i have nextjs project where i'm using BEM,

in Header.js

```
<div className={style.header}>
  <div className={style.header__logo}>Logo</div>
</div>
```

in Header.module.css

```
.header{
   height:100%;
   &__logo {
     height:100px;
   }
 }
```

when i run i'm getting

Syntax error: Selector "&__logo" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id), can anyone please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: You are using CSS preprocessors syntax in a ```.css``` file

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `sass` package to you're project and rename your `*.css` files to `*.scss` as stated in the [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#sass-support).